# Meteor - Cannot Access All Read Operations

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm new to Meteor.  I've been stuck on this problem for a while.  I can successfully adds items to a collection and look at them fully in the console.  However, I cannot access all of the read operations in my .js file.

That is, I can use .find() and .findOne() with empty parameters.  But when I try to add .sort or an argument I get an error telling me the object is undefined.

Autopublish is turned on, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  These calls are being made directly in the client.

This returns something--

```
Template.showcards.events({
  "click .play-card": function () {
    alert(Rounds.find());
   }
})
```

And this returns nothing--

```
Template.showcards.events({
  "click .play-card": function () {
    alert(Rounds.find().sort({player1: -1}));
   }
})
```

Sorry for the newbie question.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor's collection API works a bit differently from the mongo shell's API, which is understandably confusing for new users. You'll need to do this:

```js
Template.showcards.events({
  'click .play-card': function() {
    var sortedCards = Rounds.find({}, {sort: {player1: -1}}).fetch();
    console.log(sortedCards);
  }
});
```

See [this](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) for more details. Also note that logging a cursor (the result of a find) probably isn't what you want. If you want to see the contents of the documents, you need to [fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) them.

Comment: David--thank you so much.  This worked perfectly.  I read about cursors in the documentation, but must have missed the section on #fetch.  The references are hugely helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Rounds.find().sort({player1: -1})` returns a cursor, so you will want to do this:

```
Rounds.find().sort({player1: -1}).fetch();
```

Note that this returns an `Array` of document objects. So you would do something more like this:

```
docs = Rounds.find().sort({player1: -1}).fetch();
alert(docs[0]);
```

Comment: Hey Steve--thank you so much.  This is really helpful--especially pointing out that an array, rather than one item, is returned.  However, the syntax above did not work for me as-is.  I couldn't get it to work using #find and then #sort.  But I was able to get it using #find with sort as the second argument (written out in the answer above).  But the real trick was that I was oblivious to #fetch.  Thanks for teaching me!

Comment: Sorry about the syntax. Writing lots of Ruby... The MongoDB friendly way is definitely to use the `selector, options` form, as you discovered. Also of note is that the pattern `find().fetch()[0]` is so commonly used that Meteor provides `findOne()` to save keystrokes.